# How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I have an existing Rails app on GitHub and deployed on Heroku. I'm trying to set up a new development machine and have cloned the project from my GitHub repository. However, I'm confused as to how to link this folder up to Heroku. Originally, I used the `heroku create` command, but obviously I don't want to do that this time since it will create another Heroku instance.

Answer (score 1337, accepted):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) links your projects based on the `heroku` git remote (and a few other options, see the update below). To add your Heroku remote as a remote in your current repository, use the following command:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git
```

where `project` is the name of your Heroku project (the same as the `project.heroku.com` subdomain). Once you've done so, you can use the `heroku xxxx` commands (assuming you have the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installed), and can push to Heroku as usual via `git push heroku master`. As a shortcut, if you're using the command line tool, you can type:

```
heroku git:remote -a project
```

where, again, `project` is the name of your Heroku project (thanks, [Colonel Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115798/62082)). You can name the Git remote anything you want by passing `-r remote_name`.

**[Update]**

As mentioned by Ben in the comments, the remote doesn't need to be named `heroku` for the gem commands to work. I checked [the source](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/base.rb), and it appears it works like this:

1. If you specify an app name via the `--app` option (e.g. `heroku info --app myapp`), it will use that app.
2. If you specify a Git *remote* name via the `--remote` option (e.g. `heroku info --remote production`), it will use the app associated with that Git remote.
3. If you specify no option and you have `heroku.remote` set in your Git config file, it will use the app associated with that remote (for example, to set the default remote to "production" use `git config heroku.remote production` in your repository, and Heroku will run `git config heroku.remote` to read the value of this setting)
4. If you specify no option, the gem finds no configuration in your `.git/config` file, and the gem only finds one remote in your Git remotes that has "heroku.com" in the URL, it will use that remote.
5. If none of these work, it raises an error instructing you to pass `--app` to your command.

Comment: If you try to use the `heroku git:remote` method, check that you're using the heroku toolbelt cli, and that you don't have any heroku gem still installed on your system (seems it didn't work for me with the old gems).

Comment: Also, for multiple heroku branches you can use `$ git config heroku.remote <appname>` to set default app so you can use terminal commands for that app.

Comment: I had a rights error with the first method, the second did work
`heroku git:remote -a project`

Comment: Is the remote url mentioned somewhere in the dashboard? I have that every time I have to add a remote manually (not through toolbelt) i have to [look up the pattern in the help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: if using http i.e. `heroku login` then the remote is of the form `https://git.heroku.com/project-name.git`

Comment: This answer should be at the top of the official Heroku page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: Had the same problem as @pansay; simply doing `git remote add ...` can lead to error `Permission denied (publickey)`. Probably because I didn't upload my SSH key to my heroku account. If using `heroku git:remote ...` this problem does not appear (probably uses another way of identification)

Comment: This helped me, so i'm sharing: `git remote add heroku git.heroku.com:project.git` ; It's a subtle difference. Notice though, in my example, there is a significant lack of an "@" symbol, compared with the first suggestion in the top answer above: `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git`

Comment: Note: Heroku now describes it in the project overview: Navigate to https://dashboard.heroku.com/, click your app, then switch to the "deploy" tab and choose the deployment method "Heroku git" (selected by default). Then, you'll get instructions on how to connect an existing folder/git with Heroku.

Answer (score 250):

The [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command) has an easy shortcut for this. For an app named 'falling-wind-1624':

```
$ heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624
Git remote heroku added.
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote

Comment: `!    Resource not found`

Comment: You can name the remote anything you want by passing `-r other_remote_name`

Comment: This is still the correct way to do it even if you've connected your Heroku app directly to GitHub. Note it will not overwrite your "origin" remote; it creates a "heroku" remote instead.

Comment: i am new to heroku and it is showing.. `set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/my-service.git` .. what to do now?..

Answer (score 147):

Don't forget, if you are also on a machine where you haven't set up heroku before

```
heroku keys:add
```

Or you won't be able to push or pull to the repo.

Comment: Oh yes!  That helped me too.  I had an app where we started basic, then bifurcated "heroku" into "staging" and "production".  So I did `git remote add staging git@staging.xx:yy.git` and `git remote add production git@production.xx:yy.git` -- but that wasn't enough.  When I tried to do `git push staging master` (or production) I'd get "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly".  What fixed that error was to do `heroku keys:add` as Ghoti mentions.

Answer (score 15):

```
heroku login 

git init

heroku git:remote -a app-name123
```

then check the remote repo :

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 14):

Two things to take care while setting up a new deployment System for old App

1. To check your app  access to Heroku (especially  the app)

```
heroku apps
```

it will list the  apps you have access to 
if you set up for the first time, you probably need to

```
heroku keys:add
```

2. Then set up your git remote

For already created  Heroku app, you can easily add a remote to your local repository with the `heroku git: remote` command. All you need is your Heroku app’s name:

```
heroku git:remote -a appName
```

you can also rename your remotes with the git remote rename command:

```
git remote rename heroku heroku-dev(you desired app name)
```

then You can use the git remote command to confirm that a remote  been set for your app

```
 git remote -v
```

Answer (score 4):

Use heroku's fork

1. Use the new "heroku fork" command! It will copy all the environment and you have to update the github repo after!

   ```
   heroku fork -a sourceapp targetapp
   ```
2. Clone it local

   ```
   git clone git@heroku.com:youamazingapp.git
   ```
3. Make a new repo on github and add it

   ```
   git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/your_repo.git
   ```
4. Push on github

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should probable start ssh-agent and add your keys. Check this,

http://wordgraphs.com/post/5000/Heroku--Permission-denied--publickey---fatal--Could-not-read-from-remote-repository-

It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I've my project in github and heroku, for upload an heroku use :

```
heroku git:remote -a <project>
```

The doc it is:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 0):

for existing repository

type in terminal

$ heroku git:remote -a example

[image]