# Using external hard drive, heroku 2.4.0 commands are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, restart

I've configured the keys to my heroku, and I've gotten far enough to be able to commit and push onto my heroku server. But for some reason, commands like "heroku logs" or "heroku rake" or "heroku restart" bring up "no such file or directory" errors. Similarly, heroku restart -app "" bring up an "app not found!" even though I'd typed everything correctly.

I think this may have to do with my Github repo being stored and written on an external hard drive. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you create/copy the repo on/to the drive, or did you clone it from somewhere? If you cloned it, you may need to set up your Heroku remote. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app/5129733#5129733).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are in the project folder that your application lives in. It doesn't matter where the project is as git and the project git config (including remotes) will all be local to the project folder iteself.

Also, you don't actually need to be in the project folder if you explicitly pass the application name,

eg;

```
heroku rake db:migrate --app myappnamehere
```

This also arises if you don't have your heroku remote not named heroku. Eg, I typically call my heroku remotes based off the environment eg, production, development. So my typical push looks like;

```
git push production mybranch:master
```

In this scenario when you issue a heroku command it is unable to locate the application name which is does by inspecting the git config for a 'heroku' remote so it will always say application not specified which is why you then need to pass it in explicitly via --app attribute.

Answer (score 1):

An external hard drive will have nothing to do with this problem.

Make sure you are in your app.

```
cd myap
```

Then you need to create a repo and add your project to it:

```
git init
git add.
git commit -m 'master'
```

Then you need to create a heroku project:

```
heroku create
heroku rename myapp
git push heroku master
```

Make sure you have done all of that in that order.

Comment: I've already done this.

>I've gotten far enough to be able to commit and push onto my heroku server