# How to attach my repo to heroku app

Tags: heroku

I create a heroku app and then my machine crashed. I have a new machine. How do I attach my existing app to heroku app. When I visit heroku page the url for my app is like this

```
git@heroku.com:myapp.git
```

I can't do clone this app because I already have `myapp` from github. So I need to add heroku as remote to my existing github app. Anyone knows the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**If you've heroku toolbelt:**

If you're using the Heroku Toolbelt, the newer syntax is

`heroku git:remote -a project`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app) for more.

Credits: `user101289`'s solution

**Else if you don't have heroku toolbelt:**

First do this:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:{heroku-app-name}.git
```

Then do this:

```
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

Comment: I have a free Heroku account, and seemed to have to swap git@... with this:
https://git.heroku.com/{app}.git

Comment: For me 'git remote add https:// git.heroku.com / {heroku-app-name}.git' seemed to work.

Answer (score 96):

If you're using the Heroku Toolbelt, the newer syntax is

`heroku git:remote -a project`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app) for more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using just [*Git*](https://git-scm.com/downloads) without installing the *Heroku Toolbelt*, you can also create a new application.

Login to your account and go to this link

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps

Look at the plus sign on the top right corner then select

*Create new app*

Leave the application name blank to let heroku choose one for you.
Let say your heroku app name is *new-app-xxxxx*, so to test on adding a file in to it you may try the following command:

```
git clone https://git.heroku.com/<new-app-xxxxx>.git
cd <new-app-xxxxx>
echo "my test file" > test.txt
git add .
git commit . -m "my test on commit" 
git push
```

Put empty (blank) when the Git prompt for username, and your API Key for the password. You can get your API Key by showing it from the link below.

https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

Note: You cannot authenticate with the Heroku HTTP Git endpoint using your Heroku username (email) and password. Use an API key as described *[here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication)*.