# Deploy existing repo to heroku with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, heroku, github

I work on a web application I would like to deploy to heroku. I'm using Eclipse with eGit so my project is already managed with Gig locally and remotly on github. I know that there is a plugin for Heroku on Eclipse, I read the doc, but did not find how to create and push an existing repo to Heroku ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach my repo to heroku app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877915/how-to-attach-my-repo-to-heroku-app)

Comment: The Eclipse plugin is deprecated. Please follow this guide instead https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without eclipse, you just add a remote with the Git URL for the Heroku app.  For example, if the app is 'tubby-rabbit-9876' then on the command line:

```
git add remote heroku git@heroku.com:tubby-rabbit-9876.git
```

However one adds a remote within Eclipse, do that.

**UPDATE0**

Within Eclipse, add a remote using:
"Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > Repository Settings > Add Entry..."

Comment: thanks, but I work on windows (ok I'm lazy...) with Eclipse, and ssh keys are easier to manage here for me. I know how to create a brand new repo on Heroku, but not from one existing.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot, Terry. But would you mind elaborate more about the steps after `Add Entry`? How do I fill the `Key` and `Value`, specifically for Heroku?