# I got error while using "git push heroku master"

Tags: python, heroku, github

I'm using the below given commands for push data to heroku app.

```
git clone https://git.heroku.com/bigpro.git
cd bigpro
git add .
git commit . -m "my test on commit" 
git push heroku master
```

When I used `git push heroku master` I got something like this..

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I gave `heroku open` command, I got an error which is

```
▸    ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443
```

When I got the above error I tried to change commands on terminal by using `heroku git:clone -a bigpro` and after  made my changes, I gave `git push heroku master` ,I got an error

```
 remote: ! Push rejected to bigpro. remote: To git.heroku.com/bigpro.git ! 
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'git.heroku.com/bigpro.git';
```

Comment: You have to add heroku as a remote. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877915/how-to-attach-my-repo-to-heroku-app

Answer (score 2):

First, install the [heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com), and then type `heroku login` to setup your account properly.

Next, type `heroku git:clone -a myapp` where `myapp` is the name of your application in Heroku. This will pull the repository and setup the remotes correctly for you.

Next, make your changes as usual.

Then you can do `git push heroku master`

Comment: I already installed heroku toolbelt. I used "heroku git:clone -a bigpro" .After made my changes, I gave "git push heroku master" ,I got an error "remote: ! Push rejected to bigpro.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/bigpro.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bigpro.git'  "

Comment: Please update the question with the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I cloned from heroku a second copy of my files. Suddenly `git push heroku master` wouldn't work and I'd get the same error as you. But when I tried `git push origin master`, it worked fine.