# Upgrading from Heroku Bamboo stack to a Cedar stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, cedar

I am upgrading my app from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1. To do this I need to upgrade my Heroku stack to Cedar rather than Bamboo which is currently on.

I am going through the [following tutorial](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) 
and am getting stuck at the part where I deploy `git push heroku master`. When I run this git assumes I am pushing to my Bamboo app, when I really want to deploy to my new Cedar stack.

```
PhotoRambler tonybeninate$ heroku apps
  photoramblr
  young-river-1492
```

young-river-1492 is my new Cedar app, but I have no idea how to deploy to it. Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Or do I need to delete my Bamboo stack first?

Comment: Check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app/5129733#5129733) which explains how Heroku decides which app to push to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tutorial on [migrating to the Cedar stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration) - specifically the part on [creating a new Cedar app and deploying](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration#create-cedar-app). You're on the right track - you just need to specify which app git should push to, since you now have more than once to choose from.

- Find out what the remote is called for your new app

`>git remote`

- Push to the new remote

`>git push young-river-1492-heroku young-river-1492`

You can also rename your remote with `git remote rename`.

If you prefer, you could edit your config file instead, ala [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767732/28037), or edit the config after you've successfully pushed once with the long form to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

No, your `.git/config` still thinks `heroku` is your old application.  If you crack open that file and edit the `heroku` remote then it will start pushing to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried checking how you added your heroku repo for the new app? ie

```
 git remote remove heroku #to remove the link to photoramblr

 git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:young-river-1492.git # to add the new one
```

and then

```
 git push heroku master
```

You might also want to remove your bamboo app once the new once is up, otherwise you'll need to specify what app for heroku commands ie:

```
 #instead of 
 heroku rake db:migrate
 #you'll have to do
 heroku rake db:migrate --app young-river-1492
```