# Heroku Deploy Error: Cannot find module './errors/cast'

Tags: node.js, git, angularjs, heroku, yeoman

I built my app using yeoman angular-fullstack generator and then modified for my own purposes. I built the dist folder to deploy to heroku using yo angular-fullstack:deploy heroku. It creates a new heroku app for me and when I cd into the dist folder and git push heroku master everything works great.

I want to be able to add my existing heroku app to the deployment process for this dist folder so I followed this post [How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app). I'm able to then deploy to my own app with a different remote name than heroku.

I keep getting the same error when it starts to run on heroku. I can't figure out why the exact same code runs fine on the app created for me but not my existing app. It's almost like I need to clear the node_modules and push again?

```
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.989439+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './errors/cast'
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.991555+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.991785+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:36         4:17)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error.js:32:27)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996351+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    2014-02-21T04:43:51.996560+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    2014-02-21T04:43:53.457214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is my packages.json from the dist folder

```
   {
       "name": "myapp",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "dependencies": {
         "express": "~3.4.3",
         "lodash": "~2.4.1",
         "mongoose": "~3.5.5",
         "mongoose-unique-validator": "~0.3.0",
         "connect-mongo": "~0.4.0",
         "passport": "latest",
         "passport-local": "latest",
         "passport-facebook": "latest",
         "passport-twitter": "latest",
         "passport-google": "latest",
         "ejs": "~0.8.4"
       },
       "engines": {
         "node": ">=0.10.0"
        },
        "scripts": {
          "test": "grunt test"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is almost certainly that you haven't checked in all the files you need. If you can't see the problem in your git repository, try running `heroku run bash` and using `cd`, `ls`, and `more` to look around what's getting deployed to Heroku and see what is missing.

Your problem is likely that you have `require('./errors/cast')` but have not checked in a cast file.

**Update:**

The other likelihood is that you checked in `./errors/Cast` on OS X which is case insensitive, but the file can't be found on Linux which is case sensitive.

Comment: The case insensintive/sensitive part solved the same problem for me