# Setting up an existing Heroku application on a new machine

Tags: heroku

I've an existing project that works fine on another machine, but I've just upgraded and from within the project development directory, everytime I run a heroku command I have to post-fix it with --app

I feel like I've missed an application setup stage, but I can't figure out what, as everytime it states:
Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.

Help appreciated.

Comment: ahh, then this appears in related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by adding the Heroku app to your .git/config folder.

If you are in the root of your project, run the following command:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

This will set a line in your .git/config file which the `heroku` command line tool uses to figure out what `app` you're using :)

Answer (score 3):

In other words, your local repo doesn't have Heroku app URL configured  against an app name

Similarly what we do with git remote add ( we pass git URL as a destination for push/pulling of code ) 
that how our git know which repo/URL to hit (push/pull from )

Heroku also follows the same method/process.
All you have to do is add Heroku app URL (so that ur Heroku command have a reference for app URL )

it will know against which URL you are running your command against

To confirm if remote named Heroku has been set for your app:
`git remote -v`

if not configured or if you want it for an existing app

`heroku git:remote -a app_name`

it's a way to link your folder to the Heroku app

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku recommended way:

```
heroku git:remote -a my-heroku-app-id -r what-i-want-to-call-it
```

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from an app folder *or specify which app to use with --app APP*

The other answers address the first part of that statement, it is perfectly acceptable to run heroku commands in any directory. For example I have a customer facing front end project `/front-end` and a rails based `/back-end` project. I often work in the `/front-end` directory and if I have to connect to the production database I'll run `heroku run rails c -a back-end`. After I exit `irb` then I'm back in my desired directory.