# Changing Heroku management correctly

Tags: heroku, github, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

I have an app on Github that was shared by my team but 1 person controlled the Heroku updates.  That person is leaving and transferred the administrative permissions on Heroku to me.  The Heroku app is now correctly linked to my Heroku account.

Currently I forked the Github repository to my local.  How do I initiate the Heroku app on this forked repository? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a git remote pointing to your Heroku app as done here: [How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app)

Then you simply do a git push to Heroku to deploy the latest version of your app. Also see the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code) on this.

Comment: Thank you for connecting me to that link.  Very straight forward, much appreciated!