# Running bash on heroku won't work

Tags: bash, heroku

I am trying to run bash on heroku to test it out and it is failing

> ```
>  $ heroku run bash
>  ▸    Error: No app specified
>  ▸    Usage: heroku run --app APP
>  ▸    We don't know which app to run this on.
>  ▸    Run this command from inside an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP
>  ▸    
>  ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands
>
>
>  $ heroku run --app bash
>  ▸    Usage: heroku run COMMAND
>  ▸    
>  ▸    Example: heroku run bash
> ```

So, the example says `heroku run bash` will work but it doesn't. I have no dynos running. I feel I am missing something basic here...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try run commands:

First you need to login, then you to see your apps and finally run bash

```
heroku login
```

Insert you user and password

```
heroku apps
=== user@gmail.com Apps
myaplication
```

then look at the list apps and write

```
heroku run bash --app myaplication
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this:
get app name using;

```
heroku apps
```

then set heroku remote;

```
heroku git:remote -a yourappname
```

and finally run bash on/in your app

```
heroku run bash
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two issues.

Firstly, you need to run bash within some app. You can either specify the app via the --app key as the help actually says or you can run this command inside the folder which has a heroku app initialized already. For connecting the folder to a heroku app - see this answer [How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app).

Second, running a bash actually takes away one dyno from your app. So you need to have at least one dyno.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```sh
heroku pg:psql -a appname
```

Comment: Is there a reason this approach is preferable over the accepted answer? If so, it might be useful to include that in your answer.