# Requests works locally but not deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, url, heroku

This code works locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. (Note: urllib.parse works fine — news_link prints.)

```
   import urllib.parse as url_parse
    url = rurl
    news_link = url_parse.unquote(url).split("?u=")[1].split("?fbclid")[0]
    print("here comes the news_link")
    print(news_link)
    import requests
    final_link = requests.get(news_link)
    print("here comes the final_link.url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include requests in the requirements.txt file, check if it is there and in case it is you can try opening the bash console using [this answer indications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857787/running-bash-on-heroku-wont-work) and run a pip freeze to see if it actually is installed or not.