# Retrive file changes after depolyment

Tags: heroku

*(I discovered Heroku yesterday)*

I've deployed an App on Heroku, and it works just fine.

Problem is, my app saves some stuff inside .json files, so the deployed app contains new information.
**How do I retrieve it?**

I tried using ***heroku git*** but it just pulls the version at the moment of the deploy, non the one that has been changed at runtime.

Comment: The json exists as long as the dyno is running. And the dyno is resetted at which point the data will also be lost. You can run bash on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857787/running-bash-on-heroku-wont-work though I don't know if you will see the file with it.

Comment: I tried by using heroku ps:copy and it has the updated files. The problem becomes whether or not I'm able to retrieve it even when the heroku's app state becomes down/crashed.

Comment: It isn't possible; the Heroku filesystem is ephemeral so all files are deleted when a file crashes/shuts down