# How can I connect a git repository to heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, github

I'm trying to connect my heroku app to git repository.And also I can't able to push an existing repository with heroku app.While I'm trying to push with

```
git push heroku master
```

I found

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Show the commands you used to define the `heroku` remote.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the heroku app and want to connect it you can use the [cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) to list your apps `heroku apps`

```
=== name@email.com Apps
app_name
app_name_2
```

Then connect it with can use `heroku git:remote -a app_name` as well

From this question: [How to connect to the selected app with heroku CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704791/how-to-connect-to-the-selected-app-with-heroku-cli)

It is worth noting that this does basically the same thing as creating the remote as @rdegges suggested.

You can check to make sure you are

1. In the correct (git) directory and have [cloned it down](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github/cloning-a-repository)
2. Have the heroku remote to push to

By running `git remote -v`, should look something like this:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/app_name.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/app_name.git (push)
origin  git@ssh.route/app_name.git (fetch)
origin  git@ssh.route/app_name.git (push)
```

Found a very well thought out and thorough answer to heroku in general here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129733/5491808

Answer (score 0):

That error means that: in your current project you have not yet 'initialized' Heroku.

Are you creating a NEW Heroku app? If so, you can run the following command to fix things:

```
heroku create
```

If you're trying to work with an EXISTING Heroku app, you need to setup your 'heroku remote' by doing the following:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git
```

Comment: usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from

Comment: Are you trying to use an existing Heroku app? Or create a new one? The error you are showing looks like you aren't using the `git remote` command I pasted above correctly.

Comment: I'm creating a new heroku app. But I have an existing repository in Github.

Comment: Then use the first command in the root of your project: `heroku create`. That will initialize the heroku remote for you. Once you've run `heroku create`, if you say `cat .git/config` you will see what I mean. You should then be able to do `git push heroku master` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect with Heroku from anywhere you need these 3 files-

- File name ***`Procfile`*** ( generic file - no file extension)
- File name ***`runtime.txt`***
- File name ***`requirements.txt`***

For details [github link](https://github.com/iAmKankan/Data-Gathering-And-Preprocessing/tree/main/Deployment/heroku#readme)
(please fork it & give me a star)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).