# How to connect to the selected app with heroku CLI

Tags: git, heroku

I'm attempting to deploy my Java web app on Heroku. When I was making a tutorial I've created an app using *heroku create* command, lets say it wasy "name-app1". Then I removed it after the tutorial and create the new one to deploy it let it be: "new_app". However, when I attempt to do anything like upload my code there was an error that previous app "name-app1" does not exist anymore. When I try to use for e.g. heroku logs there is following error:

```
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help
```

I tired to point at my new app with following command:

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:hidden-ridge-8790.git
```

I think I messed up something and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The way you try to set your remote for heroku is incorrect. That is why you get the above error.
To set your remote correctly use the below command

```
heroku git:remote -a new_app
```

This will set your remote to newly crated app **new_app**

To deploy the code use below command

```
git push heroku master
```

This will deploy your code to heroku app

Answer (score 4):

You're close,

`heroku git:remote -a hidden-ridge-8790`

is the same as:

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:hidden-ridge-8790.git`

give those a try, if that doesn't work show us the output of `git remote -v` and we can get you straightened out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

heroku git:remote -a your_local_app

heroku run rails c