# Issues with Heroku Git

Tags: git, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

Getting the below message in Terminal when trying to push my Phoenix app to heroku.  I can't see any issues in the logs and their status seems good on the site.  I see they had an incident with SSl earlier, but that's been resolved and not sure it would impact this.

```
Simons-MBP:radios Simon$ git push heroku master
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/vintageradios.git/': Could not resolve host: git.heroku.com
```

I can still check my git version `git remote -v`:

```
Simons-MBP:radios Simon$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/vintageradios.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/vintageradios.git (push)


Simons-MBP:radios Simon$ nslookup git.heroku.com
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
git.heroku.com  canonical name = elb050388-1429905061.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Name:   elb050388-1429905061.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.225.182.151
Name:   elb050388-1429905061.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.197.241.179
Name:   elb050388-1429905061.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 23.21.250.19

Simons-MBP:radios Simon$ ping git.heroku.com
PING elb050388-1429905061.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com (54.225.182.151): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
```

Comment: And this used to work earlier? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app.

Comment: First push I've tried today but has worked every time previously.

Comment: Try `ping git.heroku.com` and `nslookup git.heroku.com`, what do you get?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: What's in your /etc/hosts file and /etc/resolve.conf file?

Comment: Looks like it was just a temp issue with Heroku, as it all resolved it self soon enough.