# Uploading to heroku from two different folders

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have uploaded an app to Heroku. This project exists in folder called "A".

I created a new app to replace it and store it in a folder called "B". I want to upload this to Heroku, but replace "A".

I want to overwrite my first app with a project that exists on a different folder than the one I had uploaded in the beginning.

Is this possible?

I have actually tried this but I cannot do a `heroku create app-name` since this project already exists.

I don't know much about Git, so i am not sure if it will allow me to upload to one app from two different file locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have actually tried this but I cannot do a `heroku create app-name` since this project already exists.

Don't create a new app; [connect your second directory to your existing app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5129598/354577):

```
heroku git:remote -a app-name
```

Then push to it like normal. If the two projects don't share any history you'll have to force push, which comes with all the usual warnings.