# Link a folder to Herkou app (For Absolute Dummies)

Tags: git, heroku

First of all, I am well aware that there is already an answered question with an almost identical title:

[How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app)

**Why am I asking the same question:**

I tried to follow it through, but I really don't understand half of the stuff mentioned there, and randomly executing some of the commands didn't work for me - and I have obviously no idea why.

I use Heroku and Git because there is no other way for me to use the tool that I need (oTree, in case anyone is interested), and I am just by far not well enough educated to understand what happens there and why. I have a physics/economics background, and programming for me mostly still happens in one file, from top to bottom. I would therefore really appreciate it, if this question is a) allowed and b) answered without too many complicated words.

I will just explain what I want to happen, and I guess that there is probably a very simple solution to it.

**The situation:**

I have a folder on my local computer which I called "maxims-sandbox". I also have an app on Heroku called "maxims-sandbox". What I want to do, is to put all the files in the folder into the heroku app. 
(What I would actually do, is just copy files from the folder in which I am writing a new app, and then upload it. I think there is probably a way to upload everything directly from the folder to the "maxims-sandbox", but I think it is probably too complicated.)

**What I can do so far:**

I have a folder on my local computer which I called "lecture-ulm". I also have an app on Heroku called "lecture-ulm". When I change something in my local folder, I then do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever"
git push heroku master
[some more app scific commands]
```

Magic happens, and everything is online.

**My possible workaround:**

I can create a new Heroku app, then copy everything in the newly created folder, and then upload everything with the magic commands. But I will probably run out of names quickly, and it doesn't really feel right.

So my question is - what do I have to do, so that I can use the three magic commands to send stuff into the cloud from my sandbox folder?

Comment: is your question about code, static images? or user-uploaded media?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't really understand your question? My best summary is "send stuff into the cloud". But I solved it anyway now, just keeping the question in case someone stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it:

1. Go to the app folder
2. Open command line tool
3. Enter the following:

> ```
> git init
> heroku git:remote -a maxims-sandbox (<- your app name on heroku)
> ```

You can now push code to Heroku (almost) like usual.

> ```
> git add .
> git commit - m "whatever"
> git push heroku master --force
> ```

You can now push your code to the sandbox, but you always need `--force`.

No idea how to get rid of it, but I am happy since it works. :)

Comment: you shouldn't need `--force` here. you can omit the `init` and `git:remote` commands, and only do the others on every change. 

A GIT tutorial (any) could help you understand better.