# Heroku - access errors - how to select app

Tags: heroku

I am trying to get heroku setup locally on my new laptop to be able to access an existing heroku account that has two existing rails apps on it.  I was able to install heroku cli locally and I was able to login to heroku.  If I run "heroku apps" it lists my two apps.  But two things I need help with:
1) I can't remember how to tell heroku which app the git repo in the current folder on my laptop should work with on heroku server.  in other words, how do i "select" which app i want to current work with after logging into heroku.
2) when I tried running the "heroku config" command to list existing config vars after logging it it gave me some kind of error message.  need some suggestions on what might be causing that too.
Sorry to not include screen shots of errors but on a different company right now.  hopefully you can at least help me answer the first question.
Thanks,
Edward
ps.  I found this Q&A, does the answer here apply to my question (1)?
[How to link a folder with an existing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app)

Comment: "it gave me some kind of error message. need some suggestions on what might be causing that"—how should we know? You haven't told us what the error message _says_. They're not random. The information they contain is generally meant to be useful. "does the answer here apply to my question (1)?"—have you _tried_? That would have taken maybe five seconds. I'm sure it took a lot longer to post this question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause turned out to be that I needed to add the heroku app location as a remote repo using the heroku cli from within my local git repo I had created.  I used the following command:

```
heroku git:remote -a thawing-inlet-61413
```

where "thawing-inlet-61413" is the name of the app.  You can get this by running:

```
heroku apps
```

and it will list them.

reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote